Extending __unserialize to run code before binding instance variables
Is it possible to run unserialization logic code before the default __unserialize behavior (in which each variable in $data is assigned to its respective instance variable)?
I am looking to do something like this:
public function __unserialize(array $data): void
{
    // do some clean up here
    $data['changeMe'] = func($data['changeMe'])
    // then call the default behavior
    parent::__unserialize($data);
}

However when I define my own __unserialize it seems to then prevent the standard unserialization behavior from occurring.
I could use __wakeup to run after the fact, but I may run into type errors if func is needed for type cleanups.
Ideally I can avoid having to rewrite the default logic of iterating over the items in $data and binding them to instance vars.

parent::__unserialize() does not exist. You need to handle the deserialization yourself.

@Olivier, is my understanding correct that if I don't implement __unserialize, PHP will auto generate logic that iterates over $data and bind each value to its respective instance variable?

I tried implementing __unserialize using a foreach on $data using $this->{$key} = $value; but am running into issues with private / protected properties since those $keys start with \u0000*\u0000 leading to "Cannot access property starting with "\0""

@AlexRothberg yes, that is explicitly mentioned in the serialize documentation, "Object's private members have the class name prepended to the member name; protected members have a '*' prepended to the member name. These prepended values have null bytes on either side." - but knowing that, you could strip those prefixes ...?
